# DBTech JDBC: [2048]: column store error while selecting from HANA

Tags: sql, hana

I get the following error from time to time while selecting data in HANA. I've searched a bit but haven't seen anyone encountering the same error.

Query :

```
SELECT A.Col1, B.Col2, C.Col3 FROM Current_Schema."Some_View" AS C 
INNER JOIN Current_Schema.Table1 AS A
ON A.id == C.id
INNER JOIN Current_Schema.Table2 AS B
ON A.sec_id == B.id
```

Error Message:

> `SAP DBTech JDBC: [2048]: column store error: search table error:  [2617] exception 70002617: executor: plan operation execution failed with an exception;exception 6946: AttributeStoreFile error while deserializing from file '<UT Main Column Reader>': AttributeEngine: error reading file`

Thanks..

Comment: Check SAP Support notes. According to the [note 2399990](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2399990) the errors 2617 and 6946 refer to out of memory (too much data).